# Bootstrap difference between col and row in first class and empty cell with padding

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a doubt, I'm using bootstrap v4.1 and I know that the follow code is right:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
                   Dog
             </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
                  Cat
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know if the follow code is right:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="col">
             <div class="row-sm-6">
                       Dog
                 </div>
              <div class="row-sm-6">
                      Cat
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

I have understood that there is a difference in the layout but I have not found a right documentation about it.

Do you say me if the two code are right?

In addition, when I wish to move element into a bootstrap cell I use padding:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 10rem; padding-left: 20rem">
                       <span>hello</span>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Have you some ideas or my solution is right? I have tried to create empty cell but they collapse:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
            <span>hello</span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is right, the second is not.

This is due to how bootstrap works.

First of all you create a row and inside it you can put columns. By design, bootstrap divides the screen into 12 columns you can arrange the way you want, just like you are doing with col-md-6. That means that, on the average monitor, that column would take 6 columns out of the default 12. In other words, the 50% of the width (more or less).

The second example you posted is wrong simply because those classes do not exist inside bootstrap and wouldn't work at all.

Take a look at the [official bootstrap documentation about the grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) that is the base of the whole bootstrap framework.

About the second part of your question, the col-md-3 collapses if it has nothing inside it. Usually, if a need an empty column, i just put `&nbsp;` inside it and solves the problem for me. Or, even better, you should check out [column offsets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes).

Comment: I see, but I have tried to use the second example and It works very well for this reason I have asked.

Comment: Uhm that seems weird. If I post your code with row-md-6 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k9p8q652/) it doesn't work (and that's correct).

Comment: It works: it prints `dog`and under `cat`. In two different lines.  When I write with `class="row"`and `class="col-sm-6" it prints dog and ` next cat on the same line

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean... the fact that it works is simply because bootstrap has nothing to to with it. Try removing all the classes and you'll see that it will print dog and then cat in two different lines. It's standard html behaviour for div tag.

Comment: Thank you :) And if I have to move down (in order to jump a row of bootstrap) can I use these margin (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) or is there others tricks?

Comment: What do you mean with "jumping a row"?

Comment: I mean to have a `class="row"`with `class="col-12"` empty.  In order to jump a row and after I have `class="row"`with `class="col-12"` that is not empty.

Comment: Because now I have used ` style="padding-top: 12em"`in order to jump a row

Comment: Ok so you mean just putting some space between rows? The spacing utilities you posted before are fine :)

Comment: But there only is column offsets not row offset to jump a row. Or I don't see something :(

Comment: Because you can't just "jump a row". Columns have a fixed width given by the screen, but rows don't have a fixed height, so bootstrap can't know how much height to "jump". So the only way for you to put some space between rows is to use margins and paddings.

Comment: Like this:` <div class="col-sm-5" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10rem; padding-left: 20rem">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="" 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
Is it right?

Comment: I think we are expanding this conversation too much, why don't you just open another question? :)

Comment: I have opened :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764131/bootstrap-margin-and-padding